# Remove words and keep only digits

Tags: python, alphanumeric

I have a list which looks like this:

| Column 1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| Seaworld | Ser Not123, 2345,hrt 45 |
| Holds | DER4, 54NOT, DTR |

From Colum B, I want to remove that are purely words like Ser, DTR and keep only alphanumeric like Not123 and numeric like 2345 and save the filtered result with column A and Column B to excel.

Output:

| Column 1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| Seaworld | Not123, 2345,45 |
| Holds | DER4, 54NOT, |

I think this can be done using this:

```
def filter_list(lst):
    return [word for word in lst if re.search(r'^\w+$', word)]
```

Comment: Your input/example is ambiguous, can you format it and give more details ? Also, can you show a clear expected output ?

Comment: I was trying to edit my question and upload an image but it failed.

Comment: Posted an answer below, can you see if it's what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, assuming you're working with a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) *dataframe*, use [`pandas.Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) :

```
df["Column B"] = df["Column B"].str.findall("(\w*\d+\w*)").agg(", ".join)
```

Then, if needed, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to make an Excel spreadsheet :

```
df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   Column A             Column B
0  Seaworld  Not123, 2345, hrt45
1     Holds             DER4, 54
```

Comment: I understand \w* looks for any single letter, number or underscore. \d+ looks for digits 0-9. but which line is making sure that we are removing words made up of letters.

Comment: The __*__ in`\w*` makes the sequences of letters _optional_. This way, we’re sure to match only substrings that contain digits.

Comment: The above code works but if if I have word like this: hrt45k, it changes it to hrt45. the letters (k) after the number is also removed

Comment: Fixed and answer updated ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your function you have the same iterating variable as the source variable. So change it something like this:

```
def filter_list(lst):
    return list(filter(None, [word if re.search(r'^\w+$', word) else None for word in lst]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the string contains a number or not. This doesn't require the `re` library.

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_purely_words(x):
    if any(i.isdigit() for i in x):
        return x
    return None

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column2': ['Ser', 'DTR', 'Not123', '2345', 'Some text']})
df = df[df['Column2'].apply(remove_purely_words).notnull()]
print(df['Column2'].tolist())


df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```

Output:

```
['Not123', '2345']
```

Code snippet: https://onlinegdb.com/JHWP4ZpOJ